# DM Join message not working in Discord C# Bot

Tags: c#, discord

I'm getting an error where when I try to create a DM channel for a welcome message I get the error:

> Cannot convert type to via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion.

Here is my code.

```
public async Task AnnounceJoinedUser(SocketGuildUser user)
{
    var channel = _client.GetDMChannelsAsync() as SocketDMChannel;
    await channel.SendMessageAsync("Welcome to Noice Discord!");
}
```

In my `handlecommandsasync` function I also have this at the bottom.

```
_client.UserJoined += AnnounceJoinedUser;
```

What would produce this error?

Comment: `GetDMChannelsAsync` is documented to return a `Task<IEnumerable<IDMChannel>>`. Your `as` cast is invalid, as there is no conversion between a task of an enumerable of channels, and a particular channel instance.

Comment: I dont really understand what I have to do

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, seems like you're using an outdated version of the library, I recommend you update.

Secondly, assuming the `_client` in your code is the `SocketGuildUser` that your `UserJoined` event handler gives (look into giving it a better name and in future when asking for help, provide all the code that is required), you don't need to cast it as anything and you want to await it.
And you shouldn't be using `GetDMChannelsAsync`.
(Note the plural, maybe you did this by accident? Remove that)

So here's what you want to end up with (on a more up-to-date version of Discord.NET)

```
var channel = await _client.GetDMChannelAsync();
await channel.SendMessageAsync("Welcome to Noice Discord!");
```

Or if you change to a more up-to-date version of the library, the method is renamed to `GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync`.

Comment: Yes I did want to use DMCHannel. I will update right now.

Comment: What did you use to check it? Are you using it as a nuget package and using nuget package manager in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes im using NuGet Package Manager in visual studio

Comment: What version are you on? Add this `https://www.myget.org/F/discord-net/api/v3/index.json` as a package source in your nuget settings, and when searching for updates, select this source (or all sources) in top right.

Comment: Oh, that indeed is the latest (stable) version. That's odd because I'm pretty sure the `GetDMChannelAsync` was renamed to `GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync`. Starting to suspect there's something else wrong with your project or code. Since I don't think that method should even exist for `SocketGuildUser` in 2.1.1

Comment: I dont know whats wrong with it. Ill post all my code here.

Comment: Main program:
```using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Addons.Interactive;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Noice_Bot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private CommandService _commands;
```

Comment: private IServiceProvider _services;

        public async Task RunBotAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _commands = new CommandService();
            _services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .AddSingleton<InteractiveService>()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            _commands = new CommandService();
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);
            string token = "actual token"

Comment: _client.Log += _client_Log;

            await RegisterCommandsAsync();
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await _client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task _client_Log(LogMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
        {
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);

        }

Comment: private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);
            if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

            string channel = Convert.ToString(message.Channel.Id);

            int argPos = 0;

Comment: if (message.HasStringPrefix("n!", ref argPos) || message.HasStringPrefix("noice ", ref argPos) && channel == "586243595984568327" || channel == "658707816298577960")
            {
                var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);
                if (!result.IsSuccess) Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
            }
else return;

Comment: _client.UserJoined += AnnounceJoinedUser;
        }

        public async Task AnnounceJoinedUser(SocketGuildUser user)
        {
            var channel = await user.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync() as SocketDMChannel;
            await channel.SendMessageAsync("Welcome to Noice Discord!");
        }     
    }
}

Comment: ok formatting does not work in comments, also I would take it to chat but I do not have 20 reputation

Comment: You're defining the event handler (`_client.UserJoined += AnnounceJoinedUser;`) in the wrong place. It's actually **unreachable** code even. Move it to be right next to the other event handler. And then remove the cast (`as SocketDMChannel`), it's not needed.